# War Horse died, possible to get it back?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

At some point I accidentally ran off a cliff with my War Horse which resulted in a death. After respawning, I noticed my War Horse was gone and the default Tennessee Walker was my main horse.

How did the War Horse disappear and is it possible to retrieve it?

Comment: Did you check a Stable?

Comment: I did, but i only checked the horses for sale I think. I'll check later  if its selectable from the owned horses section.

Comment: If you own the horse, by having placed your saddle on it, it should show up in the list and you can press (x) [ps4] to recall it to the stable.

Comment: I had a different horse that I bought the stable die in a similar incident, shot by bounty hunters then I got shot, and was not available at the stable. Neither to buy again or in my already owned horses. Just the Tennessee Walker. I would hope they have a safe guard in for the special horses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get it back. Once a horse dies, it stays dead permanently.

This has been confirmed by several external resources, such as:

- https://guides.gamepressure.com/red-dead-redemption-2/guide.asp?ID=46968
- https://www.businessinsider.nl/red-dead-redemption-2-players-keep-killing-their-horses-2018-10
- https://gamerant.com/red-dead-redemption-2-horse-dead/

As described in the first link:

> The situations described above can lead to one of the two results:
>
> - Your horse is gravely injured. You can still safe (sic) the animal if you have the item described below.
> - Your horse has died. You can't bring the animal back to life.

Comment: Can you buy the war horse anywhere? Or is it only available once?

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to the War Horse, Dappled Black Thoroughbred and Black Chestnut Thoroughbred, the *"Special Edition Red Dead Redemption 2 Official Strategy Guide"* says:

> Note that horses exclusive to the pre-order, Special and Ultimate editions of the game are unique in that they respawn at the Valentine stable when they die.

Comment: For some reason it does not respawn at the Valentine stable in my playthrough

Answer (score 0):

My war horse got shot. And was replaced by a Tennessee walker. It had both sandal and stirrups, which I had upgraded.
Go to stables, (there will be a number next to it, signifying at least one of your horses is there) Choose buy. Your war horse should be there, for free. It also says cannot be sold. But your horse bonding needs to be restarted.
Incidentally I also seemed to have purchased another horse, maybe a glitch or free. I don't know, but I seem to have 3 horses now.

Comment: I had the same experience.